# Policyd don't working with my given rules (Not REJECT Mails)

Tags: postfix, policyd

I want to Reject outgoing mails for spesific user so first i add a policy like that:

```
    Name          | Priority  |       Description           | Disabled
__________________________________________________________________________
    Not outgoing  |   0       | Dont allow outgoing mails   |   no
```

And add a member to this policy:

```
       Source         |    Destination     |    Disabled
___________________________________________________________
test2@mydomain.io     | !%internal_domains |       no
```

and add a new record to Access Control List:

```
Policy          |       Name       |   Verdict  |        Data              | Disabled
______________________________________________________________________________________
Not outgoing    | Reject Outbound  |   REJECT   | No outbound mail allowed |    no
```

On the other hand i have a Policy Group:

```
Name              | Disabled
____________________________
internal_domains  |    no
```

and added it a member (it's my local domain):

```
Member           |  Disabled
____________________________
@mydomain.io     |    no
```

so after all this preparation i try to send an email to external mail address and expect the policyd is reject this mail, but result is being different. So check the postfix and policyd logs but i dont understand anything. Here is the postfix logs for one mail:

```
postfix              | Feb 27 15:58:55 local postfix/smtpd[720]: connect from yartu_sync-engine_1.yartu_yartu-network[172.22.1.4]
postfix              | Feb 27 15:58:55 local postfix/smtpd[720]: Anonymous TLS connection established from yartu_sync-engine_1.yartu_yartu-network[172.22.1.4]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
postfix              | Feb 27 15:58:55 local postfix/smtpd[720]: C368F381ABC: client=yartu_sync-engine_1.yartu_yartu-network[172.22.1.4], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=test2@local.yartu.io
postfix              | Feb 27 15:58:55 local postfix/cleanup[724]: C368F381ABC: message-id=<1nznecl632etoauu6b1z6ku3r-0@mailer.nylas.com>
postfix              | Feb 27 15:58:55 local postfix/qmgr[348]: C368F381ABC: from=<test2@local.yartu.io>, size=1075, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix              | Feb 27 15:58:55 local postfix/smtpd[720]: disconnect from yartu_sync-engine_1.yartu_yartu-network[172.22.1.4] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
postfix              | Feb 27 15:58:59 local postfix/smtp[726]: Trusted TLS connection established to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.15.26]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 (256/256 bits)
postfix              | Feb 27 15:59:00 local postfix/smtp[726]: C368F381ABC: replace: header Received: from [172.22.1.4] (yartu_sync-engine_1.yartu_yartu: Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) (Authenticated sender: test2@local.yartu.io)??by local.yartu.io (Postcow) with ESMTPSA id C368F381ABC??for <zkry.akgul@gmail.com>; Wed, 27 Feb 2019 15:58:55 +0300 (+03)
postfix              | Feb 27 15:59:00 local postfix/smtp[726]: C368F381ABC: to=<zkry.akgul@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.15.26]:25, delay=4.7, delays=0.15/0.03/4/0.51, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1551272340 y14si8903503wru.408 - gsmtp)
postfix              | Feb 27 15:59:00 local postfix/qmgr[348]: C368F381ABC: removed
```

And policyd logs:

```
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 41] [CORE] INFO: Starting "1" children
policyd                | 2019-02-27 12:52:34,379 DEBG 'cbpolicyd' stderr output:
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 41] [CORE] INFO: Starting "1" children
policyd                | 
policyd                | 2019-02-27 12:52:34,379 DEBG 'cbpolicyd' stderr output:
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 243] [CORE] INFO: 2019/02/27-12:52:34 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[172.22.1.17]:33264" Local: "[172.22.1.200]:10031"
policyd                | 
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 243] [CORE] INFO: 2019/02/27-12:52:34 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[172.22.1.17]:33264" Local: "[172.22.1.200]:10031"
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 252] [CORE] DEBUG: Child Preforked (252)
policyd                | 2019-02-27 12:52:34,380 DEBG 'cbpolicyd' stderr output:
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 252] [CORE] DEBUG: Child Preforked (252)
policyd                | 
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 252] [CBPOLICYD] DEBUG: Starting up caching engine
policyd                | 2019-02-27 12:52:34,380 DEBG 'cbpolicyd' stderr output:
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:52:34 - 252] [CBPOLICYD] DEBUG: Starting up caching engine
policyd                | 
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:53:01 - 73] [CORE] INFO: 2019/02/27-12:53:01 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[172.22.1.17]:33654" Local: "[172.22.1.200]:10031"
policyd                | 2019-02-27 12:53:01,599 DEBG 'cbpolicyd' stderr output:
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:53:01 - 73] [CORE] INFO: 2019/02/27-12:53:01 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[172.22.1.17]:33654" Local: "[172.22.1.200]:10031"
policyd                | 
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:53:31 - 41] [CORE] INFO: Killing "1" children
policyd                | 2019-02-27 12:53:31,635 DEBG 'cbpolicyd' stderr output:
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:53:31 - 41] [CORE] INFO: Killing "1" children
policyd                | 
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:53:31 - 252] [CBPOLICYD] DEBUG: Shutting down caching engine (252)
policyd                | 2019-02-27 12:53:31,636 DEBG 'cbpolicyd' stderr output:
policyd                | [2019/02/27-12:53:31 - 252] [CBPOLICYD] DEBUG: Shutting down caching engine (252)
```

And here is my postfix main.cf(172.22.1.200 is policyd's ip address):

```
...
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:172.22.1.200:10031, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_recipient_access proxy:mysql:/opt/postfix/conf/sql/mysql_tls_enforce_in_policy.cf, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname, reject_unauth_destination
...
```

and master.cf:

```
...
    tlsproxy   unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
    dnsblog    unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
    pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
    cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
    qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
    tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
    rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
    bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
    flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
    proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
    proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
    smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
    error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
    retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
    discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
    local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
    virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
    lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
    anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
    scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
    maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
        user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
    policy-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn
         user=nobody argv=/usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl
    # start zeyple
    zeyple    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      user=zeyple argv=/usr/local/bin/zeyple.py ${recipient}
    127.0.0.1:10026 inet  n       -       n       -       10      smtpd
      -o content_filter=
      -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks,no_milters
      -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
      -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
      -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
      -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
      -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
    # end zeyple
...
```

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
[server]

# Protocols to load
protocols=<<EOT
Postfix
Bizanga
EOT

# Modules to load
modules=<<EOT
Core
##### I Added next line for solution #####
AccessControl
CheckHelo
CheckSPF
Greylisting
Quotas
EOT

# User to run this daemon as
user=root
#group=
```

I forgot the add the module on cluebringer.conf and everything works fine.